# Qual identificador de objetos devo utilizar?

Tags: r

Existem diversas funções que servem para identificar objetos no `R` (ou, pelo menos, "acho" que sejam para este fim), tais como:

```
class()

mode()

typeof()

storage.mode()

str()
```

que, com um simples exemplo:

```
x <- (1:5)

class(x) # [1] "integer"

mode(x) # [1] "numeric"

typeof(x) # [1] "integer"

storage.mode(x) # [1] "integer"

str(x) # int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
```

ou

```
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x), str(x)))

#  int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  [1] "integer" "numeric" "integer" "integer"
```

não retornam o mesmo resultado. Mais precisamente, `mode` é a única função que retorna um resultado diferente.

Agora, considere:

```
y <- c(1:100)
x <- c(101:200)

reg <- lm(y~x)
summary(reg)

class(reg) # [1] "lm"
mode(reg) # [1] "list"
typeof(reg) # [1] "list"
storage.mode(reg) # [1] "list"
str(reg) # List of 12
# $ coefficients : Named num [1:2] 1 1
 # ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "a"
```

e, de novo, não devolvem o mesmo resultado. E, desta vez, `class` é a única função que traz um retorno diferente.

Assim,

- quais as diferenças entre estas funções?
- em quais contextos cada uma delas se aplica?
- por que há diferença no retorno entre objetos distintos (`x` e `reg`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class` avalia qual é a **classe** do objeto. Objetos no R tem diferentes funções que podem ser atribuídas aos mesmos dependendo da classe.
Você pode usar essa função juntamente com `methods()` para identificar quais funções podem ser aplicadas no seu objeto. Por exemplo, `methods(class = class(reg))`:

```
 [1] add1           alias          anova          case.names     coerce         confint        cooks.distance deviance      
 [9] dfbeta         dfbetas        drop1          dummy.coef     effects        extractAIC     family         formula       
[17] hatvalues      influence      initialize     kappa          labels         logLik         model.frame    model.matrix  
[25] nobs           plot           predict        print          proj           qr             residuals      rstandard     
[33] rstudent       show           simulate       slotsFromS3    summary        variable.names vcov
```

apresenta todas as funções que são compatíveis com o resultado de `lm`. Faça `methods(class = class(iris))` e você verá todas as funções que podem ser aplicadas em um `data.frame`

`str` é basicamente uma forma de **mostar o seu objeto** de uma forma resumida, para que você consiga ter um rápido overview de todo o conteúdo e a estrutura dele, bem como o seu tipo. Ela apenas `printa` o conteúdo, isto é, não tem nenhum valor de retorno.

`mode`, `storage.mode` e `typeof` mostram como um objeto é guardado internamente no R. Todo `data.frame` é uma lista, por isso `mode(iris)` retorna uma lista (pois é como um R armazena internamente) e não um `data.frame` (via `class`). A diferença de `numeric` para `mode(x)` e `integer` para `storage.mode(x)` e `typeof(x)` pode ser encontrado em `?mode` (Mode names):

Modes have the same set of names as types (see typeof) except that

```
 types "integer" and "double" are returned as "numeric".

 types "special" and "builtin" are returned as "function".

 type "symbol" is called mode "name".

 type "language" is returned as "(" or "call".
```

Em que a primeira linha diz que `mode` retorna `numeric` para `integer` and `double` (ao contrário de `typeof`).

Por fim, `mode` e `storage.mode` se utilizam do `typeof` e retornam um diferente objeto; além de poder atribuir um novo tipo de objeto. `Mode` é mais compatível com a linguagem `S`; `typeof` retorna o "tipo" do objeto a partir do ponto de vista do R (veja [aqui](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/mode-class-and-type-of-r-objects)). Esse exemplo do `help(mode)` ilustra bem isso:

```
 cex3 <- c("NULL", "1", "1:1", "1i", "list(1)", "data.frame(x = 1)",
           "pairlist(pi)", "c", "lm", "formals(lm)[[1]]",  "formals(lm)[[2]]",
           "y ~ x","expression((1))[[1]]", "(y ~ x)[[1]]",
           "expression(x <- pi)[[1]][[1]]")
 lex3 <- sapply(cex3, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
 mex3 <- t(sapply(lex3,
                  function(x) c(typeof(x), storage.mode(x), mode(x))))
 dimnames(mex3) <- list(cex3, c("typeof(.)","storage.mode(.)","mode(.)"))
 mex3

                              typeof(.)  storage.mode(.) mode(.)   
NULL                          "NULL"     "NULL"          "NULL"    
1                             "double"   "double"        "numeric" 
1:1                           "integer"  "integer"       "numeric" 
1i                            "complex"  "complex"       "complex" 
list(1)                       "list"     "list"          "list"    
data.frame(x = 1)             "list"     "list"          "list"    
pairlist(pi)                  "pairlist" "pairlist"      "pairlist"
c                             "builtin"  "function"      "function"
lm                            "closure"  "function"      "function"
formals(lm)[[1]]              "symbol"   "symbol"        "name"    
formals(lm)[[2]]              "symbol"   "symbol"        "name"    
y ~ x                         "language" "language"      "call"    
expression((1))[[1]]          "language" "language"      "("       
(y ~ x)[[1]]                  "symbol"   "symbol"        "name"    
expression(x <- pi)[[1]][[1]] "symbol"   "symbol"        "name"
```

**Em resumo:**

- Use `str(x)` para ver o seu objeto de forma rápida;
- Use `methods(class = class(x))` para verificar quais funções podem ser aplicadas no seu objeto;
- Use `typeof(x)` para ver o tipo que o seu objeto é guardado internamente;
- `storage.mode` tem resultados muito parecidos do `typeof`, e `mode` usa os resultados do `typeof` e as modifica, além de ambos serem capazes de modificar o tipo do objeto;